# Fragment already added: DateDialog

Tags: android, android-fragments, datepicker

I have make my `editText` clickable. Once it is clicked, it will display `DatePicker dialog`.

```
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
 super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
 setContentView(R.layout.information);
 date = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.date);
 dialog=new DateDialog();
 date.setOnClickListener(this);

        public void onClick(View arg0) {
        FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        dialog.show(ft, "DatePicker");
        }

 public static class DateDialog extends android.app.DialogFragment implements DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener {
        public DateDialog() {}

         public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            final Calendar c=Calendar.getInstance();
            int year=c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
            int month=c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
            int day=c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
            return new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(),this,year,month,day);
        }

        public void onDateSet(DatePicker view,int year, int month, int day)
        {
            String date1=day+"-"+(month+1)+"-"+year;
            date.setText(date1);
            date2= date.getText().toString();
            return ;
         }
    }
```

If I accidentally double click on the `editText`, the app crashed and shows `Fragment already added` error as below.

```
11-26 10:16:04.745    2348-2348/? E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.project.myapplication, PID: 2348
    java.lang.IllegalStateException: Fragment already added: DateDialog{d1ca446 #0 DatePicker}
            at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.addFragment(FragmentManager.java:1219)
            at android.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:715)
            at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1535)
            at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:482)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

Does anyone know how to fix this ? Thanks

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> the app crashed and shows Fragment already added error as below

Because make a call to `show` method. check for is Dialog is showing or not if showing then discard the click event otherwise show Dialog:

```
Dialog dialogFrg=dialog.getDialog();
if(dialogFrg!=null && dialogFrg.isShowing()) {
   // no need to call dialog.show(ft, "DatePicker");
} else {
   // call dialog.show(ft, "DatePicker");
}
```

or use can also use a `boolean` flag like a switch to check Dialog is showing or not by making flag `true/false`.

Comment: @Hoo: show crash logs. have you tried it using `boolean flag` ?

Answer (score 4):

you can use :

```
  if(!dialogFragment.isAdded())
    dialogFragment.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "datePicker");
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the dialog is not dismissed on second click.

Try Overriding onDismiss method in dateDialog class:

```
@Override
public void onDismiss(DialogInterface dialog) {
    Dialog dialog1 = getDialog();
    dialog1.dismiss();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your clickListner

```
public void onClick(View arg0) {
    if(dialog==null) 
        dialog=new DateDialog();
        FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        dialog.show(ft, "DatePicker");
    }
}
```

And onDismiss

```
@Override
public void onDismiss(DialogInterface dialog) {
    dialog = null;
}
```

Comment: what do you mean by that?

Comment: I mean the onDismiss never get called

Comment: paste your complete class here

Answer (score 0):

you can check first dialog is added or not. and use showNow() method, its attaches fragment to immediately.

```
if ((dialog == null || !dialog?.isShowing!!) && !isAdded){
        showNow(fragmentManager, logTag) }
```