# Fragment already added: TimePick

Tags: android, android-fragments, datetimepicker, android-timepicker

I have two `timepicker` in my app, one for **timeIn** and another for **timeOut**.When `editText` is cliked, it will display `timePicker` dialog.

```
  private TimePick tp;
  tp = new TimePick(); 
  private static EditText timeIn;
  private static EditText timeOut;

 timeIn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {   //shows timePick
                tp.setFlag(TimePick.FLAG_START_DATE);
                FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                tp.show(ft, "TimePicker");
            }
        });

        timeOut.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
        {
            @Override
        public void onClick(View v)
            {

                tp.setFlag(TimePick.FLAG_END_DATE);
                FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                tp.show(ft, "TimePicker");
            }
        });

 public static class TimePick extends android.app.DialogFragment implements TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener {

        public static final int FLAG_START_DATE = 00;
        public static final int FLAG_END_DATE = 01;
        private int flag = 00;

        @Override
        public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

            final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
            int hour = c.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
            int minute = c.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
            return new TimePickerDialog(getActivity(), this, hour, minute, DateFormat.is24HourFormat(getActivity()));
        }

        public void setFlag(int i) {
            flag = i;
        }

        @Override
        public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int hourofDay, int minute) {

            if (flag == FLAG_START_DATE) {
                timeIn.setText(Integer.toString(hourofDay) + ":" + Integer.toString(minute));
                TimeIn = timeIn.getText().toString();
            }
            if (flag == FLAG_END_DATE) {
                timeOut.setText(Integer.toString(hourofDay) + ":" + Integer.toString(minute));
                TimeOut = timeOut.getText().toString();
            }
        }


    }
```

The problem now is the `timePicker` dialog only shows when I double click on the editText. Is it possible to change it to one click instead of double click ?

If I clicked more than twice, app crashed and shows  `Fragment already added: TimePick{f1f4f2b #0 TimePicker` error. I get one of the solution from my previous [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33936477/5261462), which is add a `if-else` condition to check whether the dialog is showing or not. But how about TimePicker ? Does it has something like  `TimePicker d=tp.getTimepicker();` function ?

Thanks .

**LogCat error**

```
11-27 07:17:40.617    2197-2197/? E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.project.myapplication, PID: 2197
    java.lang.IllegalStateException: Fragment already added: TimePick{f1f4f2b #0 TimePicker}
            at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.addFragment(FragmentManager.java:1219)
            at android.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:715)
            at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1535)
            at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:482)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

Comment: add logs  in `onClick ` method and check first click is happening or not?

Comment: @ρяσѕρєяK `log` not displayed on first click

Comment: @Hoo it happens due to editText is already focusable, place a textview instead of edittext and see what happens?

Comment: @NigamPatro But I want user  enter the time

Comment: Anyone has other solution?

Comment: @Hoo: if using Button or TextView then working fine?

Comment: @ρяσѕρєяK i never try. I only try with `editText`

Comment: @Hoo: try it let me know it working fine or getting same issue

Comment: @ρяσѕρєяK if i use button, timePicker displayed on first click

Comment: @Hoo: use `android:focusableInTouchMode="false"` attribute in EditText xml then try it

Comment: @ρяσѕρєяK Thanks, it solved ^^. But how to solve `java.lang.IllegalStateException: Fragment already added: TimePick` error ?

Comment: @Hoo: when getting this error?

Comment: @ρяσѕρєяK click more than two times..I try to solve by using your [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33936185/fragment-already-added-datedialog/33936477#33936477), but it not works in this case

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/96333/discussion-between--k-and-hoo).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is it possible to change it to one click instead of double click ?

Yes set `focusableInTouchMode` attribute to `true` for EditText in xml:

```
   <EditText
    android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
    ...
   />
```